# Sexagesimal Reciprocals - Confused About Floating Point Reciprocals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, floating-point

I've undertaken an essay for my History class on the study of Babylonian mathematics. While studying I quickly came across the sexagesimal (base-60) number system. I'm getting a decent grasp on it but I'm (almost) completely lost when it comes to the reciprocals.

Here is an image of the reciprocal table I have come across:

---

[Sexagesimal Reciprocals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLw0Z.png)

---

If my understanding of base-60 is somewhat correct then the single number values are justified by setting the reciprocal over 60 and reducing, equalling the opposite of the number.

So for example for 2 = 30 I took 30/60 which reduced to 1/2 which makes sense to me because 1/2 is opposite of 2/1.

However, when it comes to the two digit terms such as 8 = 7,30 (which if i understand is 7 + 30/60 = 15/2 = 7.5) it doesn't make sense to me because it equals 7.5 and further down the list of two digit terms it gets more obscure.

Of course this system worked for them and is a legitimate number system but I can't seem to get a grasp on this. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sexidecimal fractions we have

$$a,b =\dfrac{a}{60}+\dfrac{b}{60^2}$$

So

$$ 7,30 = \dfrac{7}{60}+\dfrac{30}{60^2}=\dfrac{1}{8} $$

Comment: Oh wow it all makes sense now. I wasn't aware that the first digit was also put over 60, from my reading it seemed as if the first digit was left alone and the rest were put over a square of 60.

Thank you very much for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Babylonians didn't have a decimal point, so $7,30$ could mean $7+\frac{30}{60}$ or $\frac7{60}+\frac{30}{3600}$ or $7\cdot60+30$, similar to how $75$, $7.5$, and $.75$ mean the same if you ignore the decimal point.

Comment: John or @MJD, is there any way to do this in reverse? Is there a function or algorithm that allows you to go from 1/8 to 7, 30?

Comment: Just as usual, split  $\frac18·60=7.5$ into integer and fractional part, keep the $7$ as first digit and repeat $\frac12·60=30$ which now has no fractional part.